# How to parse this xml file?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Hi i want to parse this

```
<entry>
<id>http://306721</id>    
<title type='text'>MY New</title>   
<photo:id>513306721</gphoto:id>
<photo:name>MYNew</gphoto:name>   
<photo:numphotos>9</gphoto:numphotos>   
<media:group>
  <media:content url='http:Ya4MIz9Y/MYNew.jpg' medium='image' type='image/jpeg' />     
  <media:keywords />
  <media:thumbnail url='htt0-c/MYNew.jpg' height='160' width='160' />
  <media:title type='plain'>MY New</media:title>
</media:group>
</entry>
```

i am able to parsing this file, and also able to read some values from the above xml document like this

```
Document doc = db.parse(is);
NodeList entries = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");            
for (int i = 0; i < entries.getLength(); i++) {
   Element element = (Element) entries.item(i);
   albumIds.add(getCharacterDataFromElement((Element) element                           
                             .getElementsByTagName("photo:id").item(0)));     
}
```

in the above code i am reading `gphoto:id` like this i am reading `photo:name` and `photo:numphotos`.

Now i want to read `url` from the `media:thumbnail` those are available in the `media:group`.. Can any one help me on this how to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below link of my SO Question, it will solve your problem and if you have any query regarding that then tell me.

[XML Parsing Using DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106287/how-to-parse-xml-file-using-dom-parsing)

Comment: one small request if i have like this <media:thumbnail url='http://lh4.ggpht.com/-o532BS_1MB8/UFL3MwvCKsI/AAAAAAAAEXc/Nwi8S5b1iZQ/s72/1.JPG' height='48' width='72' />
      <media:thumbnail url='http://lh4.ggpht.com/-o532BS_1MB8/UFL3MwvCKsI/AAAAAAAAEXc/Nwi8S5b1iZQ/s144/1.JPG' height='96' width='144' />
      <media:thumbnail url='http://lh4.ggpht.com/-o532BS_1MB8/UFL3MwvCKsI/AAAAAAAAEXc/Nwi8S5b1iZQ/s288/1.JPG' height='192' width='288' /> i want to get second url (wodth = 144) how can i get that..

Comment: Change 0 to 1 in this line, Element mediathumbnailElement = (Element) mediathumbnailList.item(1);, may be it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add those values in to object(using java pojo) and add that object into ArrayList

Comment: i don't know about java pojo, what is this, how can i read those attributes by using this..

Comment: you can refer this link http://nisha113a5.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/xml-parser-android-blackberry-j2me/

Answer (score 0):

try to use Below Code. Hope it will help you.

```
 Document doc = db.parse(is);
    NodeList entries = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");            
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.getLength(); i++) {
       Element element = (Element) entries.item(i);
       albumIds.add(getCharacterDataFromElement((Element) element                           
                                 .getElementsByTagName("gphoto:id").item(0)));   
       NodeList nodelist_group = doc.getElementsByTagName("media:group");  

        for (int j = 0; j < nodelist_group.getLength(); j++) {
       Element element = (Element) nodelist_group.item(j);
       NodeList nodelist_content = doc.getElementsByTagName("media:content");  
       URLS.add(nodelist_content.getAttribute('url')));  }}
```

Comment: When i use this i am getting this error `The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type NodeList`